# Why would I need FB's "user_status" permission if I have already been granted "user_posts"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

In Facebook API v2.3, "user_posts" sounds like a superset of "user_status". Is that the case? Why would I ever need "user_status" if I already have "user_posts"?

**user_status**

> Provides access to a person's statuses. These are posts on Facebook which
>   don't include links, videos or photos.

**user_posts**

> Provides access to the posts on a person's Timeline. Includes their
>   own posts, posts they are tagged in, and posts other people make on
>   their Timeline.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_status
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_posts

Comment: _“These are posts on Facebook which don't include links, videos or photos”_ – anything unclear about that …?

Comment: Yes, it is unclear. As stated in the question, user_status sounds like a subset of user_posts, why would I ever need both?

Comment: If you only wanted to request the user’s statuses, then `user_status` would be sufficient.

Comment: In the FB bug tracker, they are telling us we need both https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/449024225257676/?comment_id=714990305289972

Comment: That one is about getting comments, which you did not mention anything about before.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of when you would need or prefer integrating the user_status permission over the user_posts permission...

Lets say you want to run sentiment analysis on your facebook user... if you scan/analyze user_posts then you will not get sentiment unique to that user, you will get sentiment of the entire conversation, since user_posts includes posts from that user's fb friends. If facebook only offered user_posts and you wanted sentiment for only that user, then you would have to invest a lot of time and money developing a cleansing script to filter out all the noise, including posts from that user's fb friends. But luckily, facebook intuitively made it easy for developers in this situation, by opening up the user_status permission... with this permission, I can run sentiment analysis on text that is unique to that user only, **without** having to write a script that filters out all the noise. Because of such, I get user sentiment instead of conversation sentiment. So it all depends on your use case.

Hope this helps!